# Obtain Facebook page id from Add Page Tab Dialog selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am needing to obtain a Facebook page id from Add Page Tab Dialog selection. According to Facebook docs there is no response from this selection. 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/tabs

> There is no response data from this dialog, however the developer of
>   the Page Tab app will be notified via a callback URL that someone has
>   added their app to a Facebook Page.

I am interested in finding this:

> notified via a callback URL

How do I find this callback URL and how would I add this into my code?

The key is, I need to know only the page ID of the selected page. Not a list of all the users page IDs.

This is the code I have now:

```
FB.login( function( response ) {

    FB.ui({
        method: 'pagetab'
    }, 
    function( response ) {

        //Get Page ID and save it in the DB.
    });

});
```

Comment: That URL is a separate Callback URL that will be called.

Comment: Where do I find this Callback URL?

Comment: Your code as you have it now is mixing both approaches - you are trying to feed the URL that calls the dialog into the JS dialog call … you need to decide on one of those versions. With the URL redirect version of the dialog, you get the ID(s) appended to your callback URL when the user gets redirected there.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean @CBroe Can you show me some code example of how to do it correctly?

Comment: Examples for both ways are on the documentation page you linked to.

Comment: @CBro You are correct. There are 2 ways to open the dialog box. However,   I already know how to open the dialog box. Per the title of this topic **Obtain Facebook page id from Add Page Tab Dialog selection** I need to obtain the page ID from the page selected in the dialog box. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: @CBro I see what you are talking about. **Your code as you have it now is mixing both approaches** I have edited the code to reflect that. However, that made no difference in the outcome and the initial question is not resolved.

Comment: Just log the response object to console and inspect it …